# html form input acts like a disabled input

Tags: html, input, form-control

My contact form was working properly in the beginning. when I checked it in the next day after adding opacity to the form-control my Form input is not allowing me to enter any input.. it is acts like disabled input field. 
in css I just added

```
   .form-control{
      background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      border:none;
    }
```

```
<form class="" action="about.html" method="post">
   <div class="col-md-9">
     <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group"><label for="name"         class="col-md-2 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-10"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value=""/></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group"><label for="email" class="col-md-2 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-md-10"><input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value=""/></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group"><label for="mobile" class="col-md-2">mobile</label>
        <div class="col-md-10"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="mobile" value=""/></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group"><label for="iam" class="col-md-2 control-label">I am</label>
        <div class="col-md-10"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="iam" name="iam" value=""/></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 form-group"><label for="state" class="col-md-2 control-label">State</label>
        <div class="col-md-10"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="state" name="state" value=""/></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group"><label for="city" class="col-md-2 control-label">City</label>
        <div class="col-md-10"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city" value=""/></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group"><label for="locality" class="col-md-2 control-label">Locality</label>
        <div class="col-md-10"><textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="locality"></textarea></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group"><label for="message" class="col-md-2 control-label">Message</label>
        <div class="col-md-10"><textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message"></textarea>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
     </div>


     <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
     <br><br>
     <button type="submit" class="btn red-button" name="sendemail"> Send E-mail</button>
   </div>
</form>`
```

Comment: Any other changes you made at this time you can think of that may have had this effect? I've got this running in a fiddle but I can't reproduce your error.

https://jsfiddle.net/eulloa/ut8dh5u3/

Comment: Looks like you don't have a closing style tag.

Comment: @Jishnu can you check my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mahi_dinu/xhf5cvss/2/

Comment: @eullo can you check my fiddle.. i have added complete code to it..https://jsfiddle.net/mahi_dinu/xhf5cvss/